# Removing substrings with static part ending with a special char

Tags: javascript, regex, global

I am at wit's end as to why this does not work. I tested it on node trying to remove all instances of `RADAL` followed with any non-whitespace characters ending with `^` with a space.

```
txt = "RADALL^follow up blah blah- Pt continues on ~RADALL4^ test it now";
txt = txt.replace(/RADAL.\^/g, " ");
```

It returns:

```
 follow up blah blah- Pt continues on ~RADALL4^ test it now
```

I have also looped `while txt.search("RADAL") > -1` followed by the `txt.replace(...)`

It still only removes the first and loops forever since the second is not removed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `RADALL` contains 2 `L`s, use `txt = txt.replace(/RADALL\d*\^/g, " ");`. Or `/RADALL\S*\^/g`

Comment: `.` only matches 1 character, the second instance has two characters `L4` between `RADAL` and `^`

Comment: I am looking to delete any variation of RADAL(any number of character)^. RADAL is not static, that's only the first 5 characters that ends with a caret.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, your S* was spot on!... now if I only had a check mark to click as answered...

Comment: @CodeMonkey27520 Please see the answer posted and consider accepting (and then upvoting if you find it hepful).

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches `RADAL`, then any char other than a line break char (with `.`), and then a `^` char (with `\^`).

The string you match against contains `RADALL`, a 6-letter word, the `.` matches the last `L` and as there is no `^` after the second `L`, the second expected match does not occur.

According to your specs, the string you need to match is `RADAL`, then any 1 or more chars other than whitespace, and then a caret, thus, you need to use

```
/RADAL\S*\^/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0MHM8D/2).

JS demo:

```js
txt = "RADALL^follow up blah blah- Pt continues on ~RADALL4^ test it now";
txt = txt.replace(/RADAL\S*\^/g, " ");
console.log(txt); // =>  follow up blah blah- Pt continues on ~  test it now
```